# refcheck and IEEEeqnarray

Tags: ieeetran, refcheck

I would like to use the `refcheck` package to check for unused labels. Is there any way to make it compatible with `IEEEeqnarray`? Compiling the following MWE does not print a label next to the equation. (A warning does show up in the log file but the document I'm writing is far too long digest the log efficiently.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{c}
  x=0
  \label{eq:1}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm afraid that extensive work should be done on `refcheck`, in order to support `IEEEeqnarray`.

Comment: Thanks, that's too bad.